# How to set up a telephone + internet modem as 1 device?

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

I am with Rogers and my current setup is:

[image]

I think this is how Rogers normally sets it up, where they have 2 independent modems, 1 for telephone and 1 for internet. Question is, is this now considered old, and is there a more efficient technique for this? I was thinking, does there exist a internet modem+router that also supports plugging in a telephone jack?

The router looks similar to this
https://www.rogers.com/web/Rogers.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=INTERNET_HARDWARE&_nfls=true&setLanguage=en&_eventName=modems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (a) it is not particularly old and (b) you cannot connect the two things together.

I am on Rogers here. The coax cable comes in the house, splits between cable Modem (Internet) and the rest. The telephone box splits off from the cable TV line. This is all in the basement on the Electrical Panel board so it is not inconvenient in terms of setup and the house wiring is separate after that point.

The telephone box is for a POTS phone and not VOIP.  It is current for POTS phones (and so it is just that technology, but I need it for our regular home phone and the phone jacks in the house.

So these two units do not go together.

You could use VOIP telephones from the Internet line and that will work. I am not sure, but I think you can keep the phone number as well.

VOIP (Voice over IP) is the technology to use if you wish to have telephones and Internet on the same line.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I see. So if I want to keep it at POTS, then my current setup is most ideal? And I want POTS because it allows fax to work which doesn't seem compatible with VOIP.

Comment: Yes, so the the first part of my answer addresses this in terms of setup.   FAX and VOIP are not compatible. You would need a FAX service for that..  I added some detail in my answer.